# How to do States/Services in Blazor 8(Server)

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor

page.razor
-parent component
- child 1 component
- child 2 component

now child 1 does an action that and says has a value that I want to use in child 2(it's sibling).
I also want the value in the parent.

I been looking as Service/States. I am doing Blazor server with and it has a "service layer" so I will refer what I am trying to do as "states"

How I seen it done would look like this

```
public class MyState {
   public event Action? SomeAction;
   public string SharedValue {get; set;}
   
   public void SetSharedValue(string value){
      SharedValue = value;
      SomeAction.Invoke();
   }
}

child1.razor.cs
MyState.SetSharedValue("Hey");

child2.razor.cs
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    MyState.SomeAction += HandleStateChanged
}
// another method to dispose later
```

Then you would do the same thing in parent and this is all good but in child2 I need to do another action of refreshing the 3rd party component with its "refreshDataAsync" method so HandleStateChanged does not work for me as it won't let me do any other actions and it is not async

I changed my code to this

```
public class MyState {
   public event Func<Action>? SomeAction;
   public string SharedValue {get; set;}
   
   public void SetSharedValue(string value){
      SharedValue = value;
      SomeAction.Invoke();
   }
}

child2.razor.cs
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    MyState.SomeAction += SomeActionAsync
}

public async Task SomeActionAsync()
{
    //await thirdPartyComponet.RefreshDataAysnc();
}
```

This does seem to work but now in the parent I just want to notify if the state changed of "SharedValue" but I cannot do this anymore

```
parent.razor.cs
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    MyState.SomeAction += HandleStateChanged
}
```

So how do I handle this? Do I have to have two state actions? Or am I completely off the mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyStateService.cs`

```cs
public interface IMyStateService
{
    string? Value { get; }
    event EventHandler<string?> ValueChanged;
    void SetValue(string? value);
}

public class MyStateService : IMyStateService
{
    public event EventHandler<string?> ValueChanged = default!;
    public string? Value { get; private set; }
    public void SetValue(string? value)
    {
        Value = value;
        ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, value);
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyStateService, MyStateService>();
```

`Child1.razor`

```html
@inject IMyStateService MyState
@rendermode InteractiveServer
<h3>Child 1</h3>
<input  @onchange="ValueChanged" />
```

```cs
@code {
    private void ValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs changeEventArgs)
    {
        MyState.SetValue((string?)changeEventArgs.Value);
    }
}
```

`Child2 razor`

```html
@inject IMyStateService MyState
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@implements IDisposable
<h3>Child 2</h3>
@MyState.Value
```

```cs
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized() => MyState.ValueChanged += MyState_ValueChanged;

    private void MyState_ValueChanged(object? sender, string? value) =>
        InvokeAsync(async () => await DoSomethingAsync(value));

    private async ValueTask DoSomethingAsync(string? value)
    {
        await Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay: 500); // simulate long task
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (MyState is not null)
        {
            MyState.ValueChanged -= MyState_ValueChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting that you used InvokeAsync to get around the problem. I actually ended up doing this as well but in the reverse I had my async method but then wrapped StateHasChanged in it to do get around the async problem.

I noticed you are using EventHandler and not Action, I have not seen that used in any example, any reason why you do this.

Also is there any problem with my way other than I guess there will be more cases were the Action might not need to be async vs actually being async

Comment: @chobo2 Thats a long and interesting debate. It comes down to your teams coding style. There are pluses and minuses for both sides of that argument.